# Set Specifc Font to a TextView independent to device

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I want to set a custom font to the textView but the font should be device setting's independent. As i have used the Below Code:

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf"); 
  tv.setTypeface(face);
```

but still the font is the one that is set by the on my samsung galaxy s3. 
I want to set a custom font that is independent to the device's font settings.

I have gone through following links and have tried the things but have not succeeded with results.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483110/set-font-at-runtime-textview)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268421/how-to-prevent-textview-font-changing-when-we-change-the-device-font-style-in-s)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clean the project it will be done.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, It is done, but i need to know one more thing that how to make the custom font set to textview at application level.