# How to set type face to textView in galaxy S3

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, system-font

I set typeFace to textView dynamically and it works well in many phones i tested, but in Galaxy S3, system font has first priority. I want my app show its font, not system font.

Comment: Maybe clean the project? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489903/set-specifc-font-to-a-textview-independent-to-device