# FontFamily React Native App overwrite with device custom font (Samsung & Oppo)

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, fonts

In React Native, I define font family for all text with Rubik font but for some devices (SAMSUNG & OPPO), the font looks like overwrite with a custom device font because that brand can choose a custom font for their device.

I don't know why sometimes some text looks like overwrite with custom device font & some text still uses the Rubik font.

Environment:

- OS: macOS HighSierra
- Node: 9.3.0
- Yarn: 1.3.2
- npm: 5.7.0
- Watchman: 4.9.0

Packages:

- react-native: "^0.47.2,
- react: "^16.0.0-alpha.12,
- react-native-vector-icons: ^4.4.2,

Target Platform: Android

[image]

Any ideas on how to make a device font can't overwrite the set font family font?

Comment: try this:  https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: do the names of your font files use dashes or underscores? I had an issue where I had to use underscores in Android to get it to work properly.

Comment: See if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268421/how-to-prevent-textview-font-changing-when-we-change-the-device-font-style-in-s and this helps https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076

Comment: How are you loading your fonts? Through the google cdn or locally?

Comment: is there any solution for this? I am also experiencing in react native 0.62.2 on oppo phone.

Comment: @KyawSoeHein did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json add the key

```
{
.
.
.
  sideEffects:false,
.
.
.
}
```